# Hide some views when long pressing on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I made a screen similar to tik-tok.
When i long-press on the screen (image view) I want to hide the other views on the screen to only show the image view.
Here is what I have tried:

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed))
userPost.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

@objc func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
  userName.isHidden = true
  likeBtn.isHidden = true
  comentBtn.isHidden = true
  moreBtn.isHidden = true
  print("longpressed")
}
```

I also tried setting the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is `usePost`?

Comment: userPost is an imageView which i want to longPress

Comment: Did you add `usePost.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`? Are you getting inside the `longPressed` function?

Comment: yes i add userPost.isUserInteractionEnabled = true . but it doesn't work

Comment: And I also want to unhide UIElements on release ImageView. please give me a suggestion

Comment: Is `logPressed` getting called?

Comment: yes I do longPressed is called

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: @user15351166 Add more code and show the UI.